# Ionic2 with checkbox

Tags: ionic2

I might sound old, but i am new for ionic 2. i wrote a code in ionic 2 for checkbox and it is working well but how do i retrieve the count of the checked boxes
Below is the code i have.

---

### checklist.ts code

---

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, Alert } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/checklist/checklist.html',
})

export class ChecklistPage {

  checklist:any;

  constructor(public nav: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.checklist = this.navParams.get('checklist');
  }

  addItem(): void {

    let prompt = Alert.create({
      title: 'Add Item',
      message: 'Enter the name of the task for this checklist below:',
      inputs:[
        {
          name: 'name'
        }
      ],
      buttons:[
        {
          text: 'Cancel'
        },
        {
          text: 'Save',
          handler: data => {
            this.checklist.addItem(data.name);
          }
        }
      ]
    });

    this.nav.present(prompt);

  }

  toggleItem(item): void {

        this.checklist.toggleItem(item);
  }

  removeItem(item): void {

    this.checklist.removeItem(item);

  }

  renameItem(item): void {

    let prompt = Alert.create({
      title: 'Rename Item',
      message: 'Enter the new name of the task for this checklist below:',
      inputs: [
        {
          name: 'name'
        }
      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel'
        },
        {
          text: 'Save',
          handler: data => {
            this.checklist.renameItem(item,data.name);
          }
        }
      ]
    });

    this.nav.present(prompt);

  }

   checkallItems(): void {

    this.checklist.items.forEach((item) => {
      if(!item.checked){
        this.checklist.toggleItem(item);
      }
    });

  }
  uncheckItems(): void {

    this.checklist.items.forEach((item) => {
      if(item.checked){
        this.checklist.toggleItem(item);
      }
    });


  }

    }
```

---

### checklist.html

---

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar secondary>
    <ion-title>{{checklist.title}} #(checkeditem)/{{checklist.items.length}}</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button (click)="checkallItems()">
        <ion-icon name="checkbox"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      <button (click)="uncheckItems()">
        <ion-icon name="refresh-circle"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      <button (click)="addItem()">
        <ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list no-lines>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of checklist.items" class="home-sliding-item">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>{{item.title}}</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox [checked]="item.checked" (click)="toggleItem(item)" class="checklist-item"></ion-checkbox>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item-options>
        <button light (click)="renameItem(item)">
          <ion-icon name="clipboard"></ion-icon>Edit
        </button>
        <button danger (click)="removeItem(item)">
          <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>Delete
        </button>
      </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Could you please add the entire `list.ts` and `list.html` code?

Comment: I updated the post with the entire code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a method in your `ChecklistPage` like this:

```
public getItemsCount(): number {
    let count= 0;
    for(let i=0; i<this.checklist.items.length; i++) {
        if(this.checklist.items[i].checked){
            count++;
        }    
    }
    return count;
}
```

Or following the `checkallItems()` method:

```
public getItemsCount(): number {
    let count= 0;
    this.checklist.items.forEach((item) => {
        if(item.checked){
            count++;
        }
    });
    return count;
}
```

And then in your view:

```
<ion-title>{{checklist.title}} #{{getItemsCount()}}/{{checklist.items.length}}</ion-title>
```

Comment: thank you very much :) i really appreciate your support